# How can I enter (login + upload images to) a webapp using Swift 4

Tags: swift, server, upload

I've got a very basic question. To automate my pic upload process I have written a Swift App that takes customized pictures. Now I want those pictures to be sent to a specific "official" webapp. Therefore I have to login to my webapp account and sent the pictures to it.

I really don't know which is the best way to proceed. Maybe you guys can help me - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This question is too abstract you need to specify the API "your" official service uses.

In general, you need to write API from your side (authorisation method, uploading image method). Then depending on auth method of your service you need to handle authorised connection - it can be session / token in url as query parameters / token in headers or some other ways. Uploading can be also different, the frequently method for it is multipart data but it can be base64 encoded string in request body.

If you have only those two requests I'd recommended to you Alamofire without any additional libs